# Good introduction to NCP and free probability

Tags: probability, reference-request, random-matrices

I am new to the topic of random matrix theory (RMT) and am looking to learn about non-commutative probability spaces and some of the applications to RMT.

Do you know good lecture notes, treatments, or books on the subject?

I came across a unital functional $\varphi$ which in RMT functions a bit like a trace (the expected average trace to be precise) and saw this defined in conjunction with commutative and "free" random variables and non-commutative ones. These terms, including "free probability" are all new to me and I am looking to learn these techniques.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I like “Free Probability and Random Matrices” by James Mingo and Roland Speicher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the resources I could gather in the form of an answer. Some of these I have not personally read but have found "enough" positive reviews (both online and from professors). Firstly, a very popular text (also mentioned in a comment above):

- [Free Probability and Random Matrices](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-6942-5) by James Mingo and Roland Speicher. A very good introduction to the subject of Free Probability **with** solutions to exercises at the back.
- Terrence Tao's [Topics in Random Matrix Theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf) based on his Graduate Topics course on the subject.
- You can also check out Roland Speicher's blogsite on [Free Probability Theory](https://rolandspeicher.com/) for a bunch of resources.
- Terry Tao also has a blogsite on [Random Matrices](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/category/teaching/254a-random-matrices/).
- I have also found the book [Random Matrices and Non-Commutative Probability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0367700816) by Arup Bose helpful.

Additionally, I came across these two "short" (lecture) notes:

- [Introduction to non-commutative Probability](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7Emusat/Free%20probability%20project_final.pdf) by Isak Mottelson.
- [Non-commutative Probability Theory](http://www.mitchener.staff.shef.ac.uk/free.pdf) by Paul D. Mitchener.

Hope these resources would help you at least get a nice introduction to the subject.